# Карточки html, css

Tags: html, css

Как сделать такие карточки 
Заранее блогадарю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А на каком этапе вы застряли?) См. CSS: background-image, border-radius, box-shadow. Если карточка задана строго в пикселях, можно не заморачиваться и иконки тоже нарисовать на самой картинке и текст аккуратно подогнать к ним.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400&display=swap");
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css");
/* Основные стили */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cards {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f3f4f5;
}
.cards .card {
  width: 260px;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 #adadae;
}
.cards .card .background {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.cards .card .background::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.cards .card .background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.cards .card h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.cards .card .description {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.cards .card .description ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}
.cards .card .description ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.cards .card .description ul li i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.cards .card .description ul li span {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.cards .card .description .button-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
.cards .card .description .button-group .btn {
  font-size: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 12px;
  background-color: #00c0fc;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
 <div class="card">
  <div class="background">
   <img src="https://excurs.od.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/odessa-2-774x387.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <h4>Обзорная экскурсия <br> по Одессе</h4>
  <div class="description">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-walking"></i>
     <span>Пешеходная экскурсия</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
     <span>8 часов</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-coins"></i>
     <span>1000 грн.</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="button-group">
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Групповая</a>
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card">
  <div class="background">
   <img src="https://excurs.od.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/odessa-2-774x387.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <h4>Обзорная экскурсия <br> по Одессе</h4>
  <div class="description">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-walking"></i>
     <span>Пешеходная экскурсия</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
     <span>8 часов</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-coins"></i>
     <span>1000 грн.</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="button-group">
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Групповая</a>
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card">
  <div class="background">
   <img src="https://excurs.od.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/odessa-2-774x387.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <h4>Обзорная экскурсия <br> по Одессе</h4>
  <div class="description">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-walking"></i>
     <span>Пешеходная экскурсия</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
     <span>8 часов</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-coins"></i>
     <span>1000 грн.</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="button-group">
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Групповая</a>
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card">
  <div class="background">
   <img src="https://excurs.od.ua/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/odessa-2-774x387.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <h4>Обзорная экскурсия <br> по Одессе</h4>
  <div class="description">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-walking"></i>
     <span>Пешеходная экскурсия</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
     <span>8 часов</span>
    </li>
    <li>
     <i class="fa fa-coins"></i>
     <span>1000 грн.</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="button-group">
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Групповая</a>
    <a href="#!" class="btn">Индивидуальная</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Так?

В следующий раз хоть картинку по качественный выбирайте или ссылку на сайт где это увидели, пришлось на глаз делать.

**upd**: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/us2ecdjo/) (sass)

Comment: Спасибо жду дальше советов от вас